# Issue With Contact Form Validation

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

I am trying to validate a simpla contact form using HTML5 Patterns and jQuery as below:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="name"   id="name"   class="form-control"  pattern="[A-Za-z ]+" autofocus placeholder=" Please Enter Your Name" >
  <input type="tel"  name="phone"  id="phone"  class="form-control"  pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}" autofocus  placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx"  >

  <button type="submit" name="submit">Send Email</button>
</form>
```

and here is the jquery code I am using to validate the field if they are empty:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myform').submit(function () {
            var abort = false;
            $("div.alert").remove();
            $('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() === '') {
                    $(this).after('<div class="err"><p>Phone Field Cant be Empty</p></div>');
                    abort = true;
                }
            }); // go through each required value
            if (abort) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }) //on submit
}); // ready
```

but for what ever reason it is not validating the form! Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `<input type="tel" />` yet you're looping through `$('input[type="text"]')`

Comment: honestly i was thinking about this part but have no idea how to grab all inputs! I already trird like '$('input') to grab all inputs but it didnt work too

Comment: `$('input')` should work. Perhaps your loop isn't behaving as expected? When debugging it's a good idea to dump whatever you can to the browser console to make sure you're working with what you expect to: `console.log($('input'));`

Comment: Ok here is what I got: [input#name.form-control, input#phone.form-control, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: document, selector: "input", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function…]

Comment: It means the elements are found. There must be a logic error in your loop. See my answer.

Comment: Have you tried adding in `console.log()` to every step of your logic? You might want to remove `return true;` for the purpose of debugging, otherwise you'll keep being redirected whenever you test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't **ANY** need for JS/jQuery whatsoever. Everything can be validated with HTML5.

Use `required` in the input field to make sure the values are not empty and use `pattern` to check contents (like you already did).

```
<input ... required>
```

### HTML

```
<?php 
    /* The form is POSTed to the same page to check the sumitted values */
    print_r($_POST); 
?>

<form action="" method="post" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" pattern="[A-Za-z ]+" autofocus placeholder="Please Enter Your Name" required>
    <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}" placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx" required>
    <button type="submit" id="send">Send Email</button>
</form>
```

---

Also best practice is to use `on`, as in `$("#element").on("click", function(){`, instead of `.click(function(){` or `.submit(function(){`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(this).val() == '') {
    $('<div class="alert"><p>Phone Field Cant be Empty</p></div>').insertAfter($(this));

    abort = true;
}
```

I gave the new `div` class `alert` because you were removing the wrong element before validating.

I modified the logic to check if the value is equal to false, not equal to an empty string, in case the `value` property isn't even set (you can never be too careful).

You were also using `after()` which gets the next sibling of an element and doesn't insert any content.

Full code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myform').submit(function () {
            var valid = true;

            $("div.alert").remove();

            $(this).find('input').each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == '') {
                    $('<div class="alert"><p>Phone Field Cant be Empty</p></div>').insertAfter($(this));

                    valid = false;
                }
            });

            if (valid) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
});
```

You'll notice I made slight changes:

I renamed `abort` to `valid`, because it's a good idea to try and evaluate for the positive thing first. It's a more explanative name too: why are we aborting? Because it's not valid (`valid = false;`).

Instead of validating ALL inputs, I selected inputs that are found within the form using `find()`. Just in case there's more than one form on the page.

Comment: Thanks Jazz but same thing still happening!

Comment: I've added a full example. @whoever downvoted - why?